# Can m4 execute user defined bash scripts?

Tags: m4

Can the [m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html#Intro) macro-expansion language execute user-defined bash scripts? consider the m4 file

```
define(`FOOBAR', `esyscmd(mycmd)') dnl
FOOBAR
```

where mycmd is a bash file defined in the same directory as the m4 file which looks like

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello World"
```

However, on executing m4 on the input file I get the error

> sh: 1: mycmd: not found

Does that mean I need to modify some sort of variable containing a list of directories where m4 looks for particular commands?

I hope to be able to run awk (or even python) scripts and stick the output of those scripts in place of the corresponding macro name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `m4` can execute external programs. You forgot only one thing: the `PATH`. Please try:

```
define(`FOOBAR', `esyscmd(./mycmd)') dnl
FOOBAR
```

Please note `./mycmd`!

Comment: I tried that. I still get the same error. The error occurs even when I do `m4 -I. foobar.m4`

Comment: The m4's `-I` is the `m4`'s include path not shell's `$PATH`. Are the rights ok on `./mycmd`? Can you run from shell (and from same directory) `./mycmd`?